# Can't call a function within a callback

Tags: javascript

I'm making a webpage with JavaScript and jQuery. I have a checkbox with id "show-hidden-tables", and the following snippet of code to attach a click handler to it.

```
$('#show-hidden-tables').click(this.togglePrivateRows_);
```

Here is the function that is called:

```
togglePrivateRows_: function() {
  $('td[data-header="Private"]').each(function(index, elem) {
      if ($(this).text() === 'true') $(this).closest('tr').toggle();
  });
}
```

This works fine. However, if I change the click handler to this:

```
$('#show-hidden-tables').click(function(ev) { this.togglePrivateRows_(); }) ;
```

it no longer works. Why is this? What if I needed to use the `ev` argument in my function?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your function to the scope like this:

```
$('#show-hidden-tables').click(function(ev) {
    this.togglePrivateRows_();
}.bind(this));
```

And for your second question "What if I needed to use the ev argument in my function?"

Even in your first approach, the `ev` parameter will be pass as an argument to your `this.togglePrivateRows_` function